# maxtasksperchild argument with multiprocessing.Process python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Process` to run functions in multiple threads at a time and got an issue about too big usage of cpu and ram. It is using more and more with time the script is working.

so I found a solution for this that recommends to use `maxtasksperchild=1` with `multiprocessing.Pool` method.

so I am curios if it is possible to do the same with `multiprocessing.Process` method? or I should vetter change it to `multiprocessing.Pool` in all the code?

right now I am starting function like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    pass #some code
    

alg=[]

for kish in range(50):
    gf=multiprocessing.Process(target=main,args=(kish,proxys,proxystr,))
    gf.start()
    alg.append(gf)
    

for i in alg:
    i.join()
```

Comment: @Alexander no but I somehow need to launch it in big amounts of threads. my vps have 4 cores but runs it with 50 threads normal. the thing is that it gets slower with time because usage increases somehow.I used to go with `threading.Thread()` but main function contains requests so the whole process was slowed with using `threading.Thread()`. That is why I go with `multiprocessing.Process()`

Comment: @Alexander it works fine at the beginning, but after some cycles it starts using more and more powers of pc. As I found out it is possible to solve using `multiprocessing.Pool` with `maxtasksperchild=1`. so my question is if it is possible to perform with `multiprocessing.Process` or how to change the it to `multiprocessing.Pool`  properly

Comment: @Alexander or maybe other method of starting with mulriple threads. It should not be possible to perform sending requests in 50 threads with only 50 cores cpu I believe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not certain if switching to using `Pool` with `maxtasksperchild=1` is going necessarily provide the performance increase you think it will... Using your current example code, you can switch to using `multiprocess.Pool` with some very minor adjustments.

for example:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    pass #some code
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocess.Pool(processes=50, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        pool.apply_async(main,(kish,proxys,proxystr,))
```